# How to have a separate _vimrc for vsvim

Tags: vim, vsvim

To get VsVim to work nicely I need different _vimrc settings to what I use for gVim.

Therefore I need a way to load different values for each.

Is it possible to have each one load a different _vimrc file?

Or worst case, is there any magic I can put in the _vimrc file to conditionally run commands based on whether it is VsVim or not?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/faq#vimrc)

Comment: Peter yes thanks, I did read the FAQ before, but missed this. Must stop skim reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Tools → Options
- VsVim → Defaults
- Change "VimRc File Loading" to "vsvimrc files only"

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/faq#disable)